# Weird Memory Leak with large dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks

I have the following code

```
int main()
{
    int* myDynamicArray;
    myDynamicArray = new int[20000000];
    int numIte;
    cout << "number of iterations" << endl;
    cin >> numIte;
    for (int i = 0; i < numIte; ++i)
        foo(myDynamicArray);
    delete [] myDynamicArray;
    return 0;
 }
```

The thing that i dont understand is that when the number of iterations input is large, the memory used by the system increases as we loop through more iterations. Is that normal?

Comment: What's `foo` and how are you determining that memory usage increases?

Comment: Most probable `foo` is allocating memory and not deleting it

Comment: try to comment out the call of `foo` and see what happens.

Comment: Is `foo` a function? Can you post the code for `foo`? Are you doing anything with the dynamic array inside `foo`?

Answer (score 1):

Without having a full definition for `foo`, this question is impossible to answer. However here are some thoughts...

It is probably a good idea to wrap `myDynamicArray` inside some form of safe pointer, possibly std::auto_ptr or in the case that `foo` might keep reference to the pointer, std::tr1::shared_ptr.

Unless the call to the `foo` constructor/function is causing additional memory to be allocated, there is no reason to suggest that increasing the number of loop iterations should affect the programs runtime memory usage in any way.

Finally, how are you monitoring the runtime memory usage of the program? Watching the numbers within Windows Task Manager (or equivalent) isn't a particularly robust solution, you could try manually tracking all memory allocations yourself (by overriding new/malloc) to get a true idea of when, where and how much memory is being allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Since `foo` is not shown and because it it *possibly* doesn't make sense to call it without the array index passed in, I'll make a guess.  In other words, I'm guessing that the real `foo` accepts some kind of array index or length as a parameter and that it accesses the elements of `myDynamicArray` based on that index.

If that is true (and it is not a simple case of `foo` leaking memory), then what you might be measuring is the amount of memory actually committed.  The allocation is for 80MB, but the commit of the memory may not happen until you access the array.  So the more of the array accessed by `foo` could cause more of the memory to be committed.

Comment: As far as I'm aware this kind of lazy allocation strategy only occurs on some linux systems, and is generally a bad idea as it can cause problems later on in the programs execution. If this IS the case then perhaps @user1252314 could sequentially access all of the memory upfront in order to force the commit?

Comment: @ThomasSampson: I have worked more in Windows and I *think* that the commit of individual pages to physical memory can happen on a page by page basis.  In other words, assigning a value to one element of a 20,000,000 element array does not necessarily commit all pages for all elements.  However, the OP does not indicate the OS in question.